# Create form for function Html

Tags: javascript, html

This is my problem, hope get some support for this.

This is my function.

```
function show(n,q)
{
  for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
  {
    s=j.toString().length;
    t=0;
    for(i=s-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
      t+=Math.pow((Math.floor(j/Math.pow(10,i))%10),q);
    }
    if(t==j){document.write(t+ " ");}
    else{document.write("");}
  }
}
show(1000,3);
```

With two inputs: number **n** and the exponent **q** it will solve all the numbers smaller than n which the sum of all the q-exponented of its digits is equal to itself.
For example: q=3, n=200, we have the number 153 because: 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

This function is OK, but due to my bad javascript skill, I dont know how to create a form alowing to enter **n** and **q** into 2 boxes, then click button "Show" we have results in the third box.

I have tried this below code, but it does not work :(

```
<input id='number' type='text' />
<input id='exp' type='text' />
<button onclick='javascript:show()'>Show</button>
<div id='res' style='width:100%;height:200px'></div>
<script>
  function show() {
    var n=document.getElementById('number').value,
        var q=document.getElementById('exp').value,
          out=document.getElementById('res'),
            out.innerHTML="";
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
      {
        s=j.toString().length;
        t=0;
        for(i=s-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
          t+=Math.pow((Math.floor(j/Math.pow(10,i))%10),q);
        }
        if(t==j){
          out.innerHTML+=t+ " ";
        }
        else{
          out.innerHTML+="";
        }
      }
    }

</script>
```

In additon, I want to do it myself, could you guys tell me where i can find guide for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks fine and will do what you are trying to do. Just there are some , (Comma) instead of ; (Semi-colon) in your code. Change them and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some punctuation issues.

Try to replace:

```
    var n=document.getElementById('number').value,
    var q=document.getElementById('exp').value,
      out=document.getElementById('res'),
        out.innerHTML="";
```

by

```
    var n=document.getElementById('number').value,
        q=document.getElementById('exp').value,
        out=document.getElementById('res');
    out.innerHTML="";
```

Comment: I got it :D
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and will do what you are trying to do. Just there are some , (Comma) instead of ; (Semi-colon) in your code. Change them and then try.

Check the solution here.

http://jsfiddle.net/JszG2/

```
var n=document.getElementById('number').value;
var q=document.getElementById('exp').value;
out=document.getElementById('res');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution using JQuery....

```
<script>
function show() {
            var num = parseInt($('#number').val());
            var exp = parseInt($('#exp').val());
            out = $('#res');
            var num = document.getElementById('number').value;
            var exp = document.getElementById('exp').value;
            out = document.getElementById('res');
            out.innerHTML = "";
            for (p = 1; p <= num; p++) {
                q = p.toString().length;
                v = 0;
                for (i = q - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    v = v+ Math.pow((Math.floor(p / Math.pow(10, i)) % 10), exp);
                }

                if (v == p) {
                    out.innerHTML += v + " ";
                }
                else {
                    out.innerHTML += "";
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It required 15 reputations to vote up. Sorry, I will do that later :)

Comment: Yes, I will, as soon as possible